# new line on comma within string

Tags: android

I have an EditText view which will allow the user to edit an address field. I want any text with a comma before it to be put on a new line so for example the following:
`Some St., Some City, Some post code` would be presented as:

```
Some St., 
Some City,
Some post code
```

Anyone know how I could do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could perform a `String.replace()` to replace all commas with `,\n`

so,

```
 String s = "Some St., Some City, Some post code"
 s = s.replace(",",",\n");
```

You then might have to do something to remove the whitespace

Alternatively, to remove all whitespace:

```
    String s = "Some St., Some City, Some post code";
    String strings[] = s.split(",");

      for(int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++){
         strings[i] = strings[i].trim();
         strings[i] += ",\n";
      }
      s = "";

      for(int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++)
        s += strings[i];
```