# Split String by Comma and centered all split String

Tags: java, string

I have a problem when trying to split the string by comma and then center all the string that have been split.

I have try to split string using the answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8368917

```
public static String split (String str) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(str);
    String[] strings = stringBuilder.toString().split(",");

    for(int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++){
        strings[i] = strings[i].trim();
        strings[i] += ",\n";
    }

    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (String string : strings) {
        stringBuilder.append(string);
    }

    // Remove last separator
    if (stringBuilder.length() > 0) {
        stringBuilder.setLength(stringBuilder.length() - ",\n".length());
    }

    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

And here for center string (forgot where is the source from)

```
public static String center (String str, int length) {
    if (str.length() > length) {
        return str.substring(0, length);
    } else if (str.length() == length) {
        return str;
    } else {
        int leftPadding = (length - str.length()) / 2;
        StringBuilder leftBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < leftPadding; i++) {
            leftBuilder.append(" ");
        }

        int rightPadding = length - str.length() - leftPadding;
        StringBuilder rightBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < rightPadding; i++) {
            rightBuilder.append(" ");
        }

        return leftBuilder.toString() + str + rightBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

Here what I have try to do

```
String STR;
STR = STR + String.format("%1$48s", center(split(Address), 48)) + "\n";
System.out.println(STR);
```

Expected result

```
        Street Road Patta 55,
         053888 Alur Satta,
              Keidaj
```

Actual result

```
   Street Road Patta 55,
053888 Alur Satta,
Keidaj
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your splitting of the string results in one single string. 
You should split the string into N strings (lines) and then center each line :

```java
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Center {

    public Center() {
    }

    public static String center (String str, int length) {
        if (str.length() > length) {
            return str.substring(0, length);
        } else if (str.length() == length) {
            return str;
        } else {
            int leftPadding = (length - str.length()) / 2;
            StringBuilder leftBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < leftPadding; i++) {
                leftBuilder.append(" ");
            }

            int rightPadding = length - str.length() - leftPadding;
            StringBuilder rightBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < rightPadding; i++) {
                rightBuilder.append(" ");
            }

            return leftBuilder.toString() + str + rightBuilder.toString();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = "Street Road Patta 55,053888 Alur Satta,Keidaj";

        Stream.of(input.split(",")).map(line -> center(line, 48)).forEach(System.out::println);

    }

}
```

Output:

```
              Street Road Patta 55              
               053888 Alur Satta                
                     Keidaj
```

**Same but without lambdas**

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String input = "Street Road Patta 55,053888 Alur Satta,Keidaj";

    final String[] lines = input.split(",");
    for(String line : lines) {
        System.out.println(center(line, 48));
    }

}
```

HTH!

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but I'm not understand about Lambda Java 8, I'm still new in Java. Can you please help me in Java in Android. Thanks and sorry for trouble you

Comment: @User, I edited my answer to add a lambda-less variant.

Comment: Hi @Highbrainer, Thanks so much for helping me, I'm so appreciate your help. You also make me interesting to learn something new like lambdas. Have a nice day. Best Regards.